# Windows Server 2008 Standard vs HPC limitations

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

Can I mount an SQL server database over 1TB with 2008 Standard?  Or would I need the HPC version for that?  I don't think I do but I just want to double check before I do this full installation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the standard edition.

For what you want to do, the only limitation is the edition of sql server, I think you can use any paid for edition. The Express (free) edition has a limitation of 4GB for database size.

As you can see, Windows itself has no limitation on file size (excluding the fact you need NTFS for large files)

See here for the comparison of the different editions of Windows server - http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/compare-specs.aspx

See here for the comparison of the different editions of SQL server - 
http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions.aspx